# How to use proc means in SAS to calculate the mean of a value and divide it by 12 (so it would show up in a table)

Tags: sas, mean, procedure

I know how to find the mean but haven't found a way to divide it by some kind of number.

[what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNTv7.png) (how to divide all the number values by 12?)
[inserted a pic of how i got it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Xkn.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You don't.  Either divide the values before hand and use that variable as the input. Or divide the result output by PROC MEANS (also known as PROC SUMMARY).